# Custom css with kaminari with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, nokogiri

I try to use paginate with kaminari. My project used bootsrap css, and the result is so ugly:)
[image]

The html is generated by nokogiri

```
<nav class="pagination">
    <span class="first">
  <a href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en">« First</a>
</span>

    <span class="prev">
  <a rel="prev" href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en">‹ Prev</a>
</span>

        <span class="page">
  <a rel="prev" href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en">1</a>
</span>

        <span class="page current">
  2
</span>

        <span class="page">
  <a rel="next" href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en&amp;page=3">3</a>
</span>

        <span class="page">
  <a href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en&amp;page=4">4</a>
</span>

    <span class="next">
  <a rel="next" href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en&amp;page=3">Next ›</a>
</span>

    <span class="last">
  <a href="/admin/book_borrow/borrow?locale=en&amp;page=4">Last »</a>
</span>

  </nav>
```

I want something like pagination in bootstrap page, how I can do?
Please help!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

After I posted this question I found the solution:
[kaminari: A Scope & Engine based, clean, powerful, customizable and sophisticated paginator for Rails 3](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari).

Just go to the console and type:

```
rails generate kaminari:views bootstrap4
```

It will download some Haml files to your application, and the views are changed.  It also supports bootstrap 2 and 3 e.g

```
rails generate kaminari:views bootstrap3
```

Here are some themes for Kaminari views: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_themes

Comment: Hi, thanks! Hope my answer will help you to save a little time :)

Comment: rails generate kaminari:views bootstrap4

Answer (score 26):

simply add following css to your application.css

```
.pagination a, .pagination span.current, .pagination span.gap {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 14px;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-left-width: 0;
}

.pagination {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    .first{
        padding : 0;
        float: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .prev {
        padding : 0;
        float: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .page{
        padding : 0;
        float: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .next{
        padding : 0;
        float: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .last{
        padding : 0;
        float: none;
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is excellent advice.  I also added one more line of css:

a:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

That adds a hover action on the pagination links.

This was tested on Rails 5.1 and bootstrap 3.

Comment: How do I change the font-color/background of the highlighted page number?

Answer (score 7):

```
rails generate kaminari:views bootstrap4
```

**Available themes:** bootstrap2, bootstrap3, bootstrap4, bourbon, bulma, foundation, foundation5, github, google, materialize, purecss, semantic_ui

Answer (score 6):

Nearly gave up until I found "[Pagination with Kaminari](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari)".

In short, after `rails g kaminari:default` go into the views that are created under app/views/kaminari and change the tags to suit your styling.

I went into `_paginator.html.erb` and changed the `<nav>` to a `<div>` and replaced all the `<span>` tags with `<li>`.

To get the bootstrap styling that fits my app, I changed the `<div>` tag in `_paginator.html.erb` to `<div class="pagination pull-right">` and the `<span class="page">` tags to simple `<li>`.

There's are a couple of gotcha's that perhaps someone else can help with:

1. There's erb in `_page.html.erb` that changes the class for the current page when active. It messes up the alignment so to get around that, change the `<%= link_to_unless page.current? ... %>` to `<%= link_to page ... %>`.
2. The `_gap.html.erb` view which inserts the "..." block also gets messed up.  Replace it with `<li><%= link_to '...' %></li>` to get it to sit nicely inline.

I just started coding 8 weeks ago so for sure there are better ways to approach this and ways to clean up 1 and 2, but if you just want things to look right and function as intended, give that a shot and fine tune later.

Comment: hi, nice try! But there is an easier way. you can use bootstrap theme for kaminari, it's automatic

Comment: Hi Duykhoa - Thanks for the comment. Hopefully the response is still helpful for those who wish to customize the theme.